MongoDB C# : insert, otherwise update the entire document
I'm trying to write a method to insert a document into my MongoDB collection if it does not already exist, otherwise update the entire document (minus the _id).
Looked at this example but it is 5 years old and some of the code seems to be deprecated (and it also didn't work): Updating whole Document if already exist with mongodbDriver
Based on a lot of other examples have built the following:
public void CreateOrUpdate(Batch batch)
{
    var filter = Builders<Batch>.Filter.Eq("_id", batch.Id);
    var options = new ReplaceOptions { IsUpsert = true };
    _batchCollection.ReplaceOne(filter, batch, options);
}

The class I am trying to insert is pretty simple:
namespace MyApp.MyService.MyModel
{
    [Serializable]
    public class Batch
    {
        // Identification info
        public string Description { get; set; } = "not provided";

        // The unique Batch Id, this will be used everywhere to identify this batch run
        [BsonId]
        [BsonGuidRepresentation(GuidRepresentation.Standard)]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        [BsonGuidRepresentation(GuidRepresentation.Standard)]
        public Guid AccountId { get; set; }       
        public string BatchName { get; set; } = "";
   }
}

But when I try to insert the first document I get:

MongoBulkWriteException`1: A bulk write operation resulted in one or more errors. WriteErrors: [ { Category : "Uncategorized", Code : 66, Message : "After applying the update, the (immutable) field '_id' was found to have been altered to _id: UUID("bf46d19b-546f-4b96-8f0c-e06883b4d70d")" } ].

I previously proved that a single insert works, so have connectivity and client is working.

if you try filtering not by guid, will it work?

@dododo Not yet what would I filter by? The collection is empty...

@dododo Same error no matter what the filter is

@AgeofEmpires I think there has been an issue in older MongoDB drivers, are you using a newer version? Great user name by the way :)

The link you shared is not relevant. MongoDB and MySQL are two different databases, one is non-relational (NoSQL), another is relational (SQL).

From my observation, as you apply [BsonGuidRepresentation(GuidRepresentation.Standard)], when serialized the _id will change to "UUID("...")", this results _id value change and get the mentioned error.

@Sebastian Should be the latest since I installed just a couple days ago. And love AoE been playing since late 1990s. Ugh I am old :)

@Yong Shun I was not using that setting, but I have found that using it actually helps with the Update if done alone. I will be updating this with my solution, though it is not optimal.

Try to replace Builders<Batch>.Filter.Eq("_id", batch.Id) with Builders<Batch>.Filter.Eq(d => d.Id, batch.Id).

@ChristophLütjen thanks tried that earlier, same error.

And you're sure you're looking at the right place? What I don't understand: All your code fragments update only a single document, but the exception is about bulk write and none of the places in your code starts a bulk write operation.

I have it working, but I had to break the Insert and Update apart. Even then it was not straight forward. I now need to know when to do the initial create and when to update. My issue is that I am doing a Parallel operation and I was hoping to let MongdoDB make that decision. Here is the final code for the client. Note the use of this code in the Program.cs:
#pragma warning disable CS0618
BsonDefaults.GuidRepresentationMode = GuidRepresentationMode.V2;    
BsonDefaults.GuidRepresentation = GuidRepresentation.Standard;
#pragma warning restore CS0618
BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializer(new GuidSerializer(GuidRepresentation.Standard));

Which is the only way I could make the filter work using a GUID as my _id.Per this article:
https://kevsoft.net/2022/02/18/setting-up-mongodb-to-use-standard-guids-in-csharp.html#:~:text=The%20BinData%20sub%20type%20of%203%20is%20a%20%E2%80%9CUUID%20(Old)%E2%80%9D
When defining the objects with Guids do the following, noting the difference between the primary Id and other Guids, the Batch class to be persisted:
namespace MyApp.MyService.Models.Database
{
    [Serializable]
    public class Batch
    {

        // The unique Batch Id, this will be used everywhere to identify this batch run
        [BsonId]
        [BsonGuidRepresentation(GuidRepresentation.Standard)]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        [BsonGuidRepresentation(GuidRepresentation.Standard)]
        public Guid AccountId { get; set; }

Full code looks like this:
using MyApp.MyService.Clients.Configuration;
using MyApp.MyService.Clients.Interfaces;
using MyApp.MyService.Models.ModelData;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers;
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization;
using MongoDB.Driver;

namespace MyApp.MyService.Clients
{
    public class BatchClient : IBatchClient
    {
        private readonly IMongoCollection<Batch> _batchCollection;
        public BatchClient(IOptions<MongoDBSettings> mongoDBSettings)
        {
            MongoClient client = new MongoClient(mongoDBSettings.Value.ConnectionString);
            IMongoDatabase database = client.GetDatabase(mongoDBSettings.Value.DatabaseName);
            _batchCollection = database.GetCollection<Batch>("batch");
        }

        public void InsertAsync(Batch batch)
        {
            _batchCollection.InsertOneAsync(batch);
        }

        public void UpdateAsync(Batch batch)
        {
            var filter = Builders<Batch>.Filter.Eq(d => d.Id, batch.Id);
            var options = new ReplaceOptions { IsUpsert = true };
            _batchCollection.ReplaceOneAsync(filter, batch, options);
        }

        public void DeleteAsync(Guid id) {
            var filter = Builders<Batch>.Filter.Eq("batchId", id);
            _batchCollection.DeleteOne(filter);
        }

        public List<Batch> GetAll()
        {
            return _batchCollection.Find(f => true).ToList(); ;
        }

    }
}


this contradicts to your above messages that your issue is unrelated to used types in filter

@dododo Yes, it worked once for the above comments, but then failed. I have updated the answer to match what is actually now working for my code, seemingly consistently. Frankly I am a bit disappointed in how C# package is handling this, the Java implementation with JPA was much more straight forward.

You use an old guid handling approach, it's better to use v3, see here https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/csharp/current/fundamentals/serialization/guid-serialization/

Thanks, I will check it out. I did try to use V3 but it was throwing errors. See if I was wiring it correctly
